# Use Image.copy in recursive deepcopy

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've basemodel that copy the model in contructor:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original = copy.deepcopy(self
```

My problem is that some models have ImageField, and when I try copy, I get AttributeError. I found the solution for this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775216/python-copy-on-pil-image-object), that says "use image.copy() instead of copy.deepcopy().

Can I implement image.copy() in a recursive deepcopy when the field is a image?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** This is the trace:

```
Traceback: 

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py" in load

139. read = self.load_read

During handling of the above exception ('JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_read'), another exception occurred:

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner

39. response = get_response(request)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response

187. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response

185. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view

58. return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view

68. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch

477. response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception

437. self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch

474. response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/imontilla/PycharmProjects/api/apps/chats/api.py" in put

107. return self.response_or_errors(serializer, respond_with=serializers.ChatMessageOutputSerializer)

File "/home/imontilla/PycharmProjects/api/apps/core/generics.py" in response_or_errors

31. instance = serializer.save(**kwargs)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save

214. self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in create

902. instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method

85. return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create

397. obj = self.model(**kwargs)

File "/home/imontilla/PycharmProjects/api/apps/core/models.py" in __init__

22. self.original_instance = copy.deepcopy(self)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in deepcopy

182. y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in _reconstruct

297. state = deepcopy(state, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in deepcopy

155. y = copier(x, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in _deepcopy_dict

243. y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in deepcopy

182. y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in _reconstruct

297. state = deepcopy(state, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in deepcopy

155. y = copier(x, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in _deepcopy_dict

243. y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/copy.py" in deepcopy

174. rv = reductor(4)

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in __getstate__

639. self.getpalette(),

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in getpalette

1196. self.load()

File "/home/imontilla/.virtualenvs/petycash-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py" in load

143. read = self.fp.read

Exception Type: AttributeError at /chats/6fbd9f3e87f945b99969b2c53e35eb66/messages/image/

Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing PIL image objects with Django `ImageField`

Comment: The error is the same that the other question, and I am getting it in PIL/ImageFile.py:143 read = read.fp.read. I am not sure how it works internally django image field, but propably it have the value as ImageFile instance (o maybe I have other model with ImageFile, I don't know all models in my project).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to add a method `copy` to your class. Within this method you may control the way to copy objects having different types.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original = self.copy()

    def copy(self):
        clone = copy.copy(self) # to copy __dict__ only
        for key, value in clone.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(value, BaseModel):
                clone.__dict__[key] = value.copy() # recoursively
            elif isinstance(value, Image):
                clone.__dict__[key] = value.copy()
            else:
                clone.__dict__[key] = copy.deepcopy(value)
        return clone
```

Comment: I need copy the values (not the references). I'm afraid to use copy.copy instead of copy.deepcopy. Are you sure this solution copy the values?

Comment: @IvanMontilla Yes, I'm sure. In my solution first I copy `__dict__` only, it's done by `copy.copy`. But after that in the for-loop I make deepcopy for each value, depending on its type.

Comment: Not working, I think __dict__ only access to properties of instance, but not of properties of the properties. I solved the problem changing ImageFileField to FileField, the FileField can supply the same action in this case. Thanks you.