# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdraw'

Tags: python, opencv

Okay so i'm trying to add an indian/nepali font for a gesture recognition system and i'm struggling a bit with the Pillow library. I followed the documentation for pillow and i'm getting an AttributeError.

My Code:

```
def put_splitted_text_in_blackboard(blackboard, splitted_text):
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(blackboard)
for text in splitted_text:
    fonts = ImageFont.truetype("preeti.TTF", 50)
    draw.text((10, 25), text, font=fonts)
```

It's giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 
289, in Draw
return im.getdraw(mode)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdraw'
```

The blackboard has been defined here:

```
def recognize()
blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    splitted_text = split_sentence(text, 2)
    put_splitted_text_in_blackboard(blackboard, splitted_text)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    res = np.hstack((img, blackboard))
    cv2.imshow("Recognizing gesture", res)
    cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

Anyone know where it went wrong?

Comment: The first arg to `ImageDraw.Draw` should be a PIL `Image` object, but you passed it a Numpy array.

Comment: okay yeah i got it, my bad
but if i want to display characters on a blank screen, how do i pass a PIL Image to do so?

Comment: You can use PIL [`Image.new`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new) to create a blank image of whatever size you want, and a Image object has a `.show` method you can use to display it. There are fast methods to convert a PIL Image to a Numpy array, and vice versa, in case you need Numpy to do some processing that's not convenient in PIL. It's probably not a good idea to mix PIL & cv2 in the one program. It won't hurt anything, but it's a recipe for confusion. ;) For example, PIL uses the RGB convention, but cv2 uses BGR.

Comment: Like if i was just to use one of the pre-defined fonts in OpenCV i'd use: 

`cv2.putText(blackboard, text, (4, 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255))`

i'm still very much confused as to how PIL works.

Comment: In PIL you use [ImageFont](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html). It's probably a good idea at this stage to spend a bit of time browsing the PIL docs to get an idea of the tools that it offers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is change this line:

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(blackboard)
```

to

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(Image.fromarray(blackboard))
```

Which give ImageDraw an Image which it can understand not a numpy array which it can't.

Comment: Sorry typo: should be fromarray!!

Comment: Thank you so much. That did the trick. 
Side question: any idea as to why openCV doesn't support international fonts? Kinda weird that it only supports one font family.

Comment: If you could accept my answer - I will edit to remove typo. Don't know OpenCV very well at all so no I doon't, maybe cotact development team via github?

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help Paula.