# How can images be modified and appended to the end of a list with python using PIL?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, rgb

Using a for loop I am trying to modify the color values of an image and then append the modified copy of the image to a list.  Every time I run my for loop, all images in my list are modified rather than the for loop generating a new copy that gets appended to the end of the list.  As a result, all images end up looking like the last iteration of the for loop. My current code is as follows. Please advise.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance

pic=Image.open("pic.gif")
pic=pic.convert('RGB')
width, height = pic.size

pics=[]
for intens in [.1, .5, .9]:
    for x in range(pic.width):
        for y in range(pic.height):
            a = pic.getpixel((x,y))
            a = (int(a[0]*intens), a[1], a[2])
            pic.putpixel((x,y),a)
    pics.append(pic)
```

Comment: Think about how many `pic`tures you're actually creating.

Comment: I see that I am only modifying one variable, 'pic', and appending that variable to the list 'pics'.  How can I instead append a copy of 'pic' to list 'pics' that has been modified and has it's own unique variable name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775216/python-copy-on-pil-image-object

Comment: You are trying to make a list of 3 images, where the first has all the red values divided by 10, the second has all the red values divided by 2 and the third has the red values multiplied by 0.9. Correct?

Comment: Correct! I believe I am just appending the same pic to the list 3 times and modifying it 3 times

Comment: Yes, that is the problem that I was hinting at. You'll need to make a copy of the images, or call `open` multiple times (although that'll be much slower).

Comment: If you do this without copying the original image, then when you multiply by 0.5, you will be multiplying the image you have already multiplied by 0.1 by a further 0.5, surely?

Comment: Figured it out with your help. Thanks!

Comment: Well done! You can add your code as an answer and accept it as correct and bag the points.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I wrapped my list of intensities with another for loop in order to iterate through everything 3 more times.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance

pic=Image.open("pic.gif")
pic=pic.convert('RGB')
width, height = pic.size

pics=[]
for i in range(3):
    for intens in [.1, .5, .9]:
        for x in range(pic.width):
            for y in range(pic.height):
                a = pic.getpixel((x,y))
                a = (int(a[0]*intens), a[1], a[2])
                pic.putpixel((x,y),a)
    pics.append(pic)
```

Comment: Hello, please add some context to your code. Help explain why this is a good solution and how it helps the OP solve their issue, as well as helping those who come across this thread understand what your code is doing and how it accomplishes the task at hand. You may also want to read this Stack Overflow article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer